# Does anyone have a design for a stand alone Keilim Mikvah to be built next to a Shul?

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

We are planning to build a stand alone keilim Mikvah next to our shul building, but can't find detailed plans.  Does anyone have plans, drawings or details about construction?

Comment: Same way you would build a Keilim mikvah that’s not next to a shul?

Comment: Building a mikve is a very complex undertaking. My understanding is that you need to call on a rav specializing in such projects. See [here](https://www.mikvah.org/article/mikvah_construction) and [here](http://koltorah.org/ravj/12-1b%20The%20Building%20and%20Maintenance%20of%20Mikvaot%20-%20Part%201.htm) for starting points

Comment: @mbloch it's just a hole in the ground and some specially fitted pipes. The overall design of the building is pretty straightforward

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting, I thought the water collection system was complex and that mikve specialists were crucial to get it right and ensure the mikva starts and stays kosher. Actually I was just reading an article yesterday that R Meir Posen (one of the recognized specialists in the field) asked that a halakhic consultant check all new installations of a simpler design that was invented

Comment: @DoubleAA I actually checked the best summary I have to the laws of a kosher mikve which is the introduction to artscroll's mishna Mikvaot. He writes explicitly there "as with the execution of a *get*, the construction and supervision of a mikva is best left to experts [because karet applies to both]"